# ExpandableLable works only for system font

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have implemented [ExpandableLable](https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel) (third party class installed with pods) for expanding a `UILabel` by clicking Read more - close when the text increases in a `UILabel`, but it works only for system font. Please suggest some way out.

*I implemented it like this:*

```
let modelData = model as! NewPostData
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: modelData.descriptionValue!)
attributedString.addAttributes([.font : UIFont(name: "Nunito-Light", size: 13.0) ?? ""], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (modelData.descriptionValue?.count)! - 1))
discriptionLbl.attributedText = attributedString
```

It works when the text size is 13 then does not work if I increase the font size.

Comment: please share the reference about what you are using and how you are using that pod.

Comment: I am using this  pod "ExpandableLabel" in pods. This could be found here: https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel

Comment: You can chackout `UIFont(name: "Nunito-Light", size: 13.0)` return a font or nil value.

Comment: ok, I will check.

Comment: Yes it returns font both times when I set font to 13 and 17, but when font is 17 it does not show read more like when it show at font size 13.

Answer (score 0):

As [ExpandableLabel](https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel) is a sub class of `UILabel` we can use `attributedText` property to set the custom fonts, colors and whatever...

```
let string = loremIpsumText()
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
attributedString.addAttributes([.font : UIFont(name: "Nunito-Light", size: 17.0)!], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count - 1))
cell.expandableLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Please check the delegate methods of `ExpandableLabel`, you might set the font size to 13 back.

```
func willExpandLabel(_ label: ExpandableLabel)
func didExpandLabel(_ label: ExpandableLabel)

func willCollapseLabel(_ label: ExpandableLabel)
func didCollapseLabel(_ label: ExpandableLabel)
```

Comment: This is also only works if I have font size 13 , when I increase the font size to 17 it does not work. Thanks

Comment: Please check *UIFont(name: "Nunito-Light", size: 17.0)* is returning nil

Comment: It does not return nil. It shows : <UICTFont: 0x7fcc21f09930> font-family: "Nunito-Light"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00pt

Comment: Are you setting the font size to 13, again anywhere in delegate methods espacially, plz check

Comment: No, I have posted my delegate methods above. there is no change in font.

Comment: Font 13 prints as: <UICTFont: 0x7f9b66c27f60> font-family: "Nunito-Light"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 13.00pt

Comment: Try to remove the _ExpandableLabel_ class, add download it from _GitHub_ and add it again to your project.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with the newly added class as well.